# Matplotlib Savefig causes fatal python error, but otherwise works fine

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have matplotlibs savefig function in a bigger python program I am writing and I noticed that everytime savefig is called I get this RuntimeError. http://imgur.com/sTdYI6p

If I run the program from command prompt I get text saying:

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate
```

The error only happens when savefig is called, and not when I instead call plt.show() Also, the function is working correctly as the fig is created and the program does not stop running. I have condensed the problem to a small example showing it. I am running python version 2.7 on windows 7 with matplotlib 1.1.1

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def graph_results(save_file_location):
    '''Graph the results'''
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 18))
    graph1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    graph1.plot(np.array([0, 1, 2]), np.array([1, 4, 3]), color="blue")
    try:
        fig.savefig(save_file_location)
    except IOError:
        print "\nInvalid Save File Location\n"

def main_func():
    graph_results("garbage.png")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_func()
```

I have found many results on google of people experiencing the same or a similar problem but I haven't been able to find a cause or a fix.

EDIT:
As per the comment suggestion I have updated matplotlib to version 1.3.1 and ran code that was as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15, 14))
```

I still received the same error.

Comment: A question: If you just leave the `savefig` out (and do not call `show` either), does this happen?

Comment: Ok that is bizarre, I just commented out the last 4 lines of my graph_results function and ran it again and received the same error. I have no idea why in my bigger problem it only was when savefig was called instead of show. Since you suggested it, do you have a feeling you know why?

Comment: You are using a _very_ old version of mpl, you should try with a newer version.

Comment: @user3666665: Just an educated guess, because this reminds of an old problem with TkAgg (the default backend on Win). Most probably you can save whatever, as long as you call `show` in the end. However, try updating your mpl as `tcaswell` advises. (Take his advice seriously, he has written big part of the libarary...)

Comment: @tcaswell I have updated to mpl version 1.3.1 and am still experiencing this problem.